# How to add new attribute in data object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For arrays vue.js good works with default array methods: push, pop, shift, reverse... But how to create new item in object and paste some value?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    items: [
      {
        start: '12:15',
        end: '13:15',
        name: 'Whatch Vue.js Laracast',
        description: 'Watched the Laracast series on Vue.js',
        tags: ['learning', 'Vue.js', 'Laracast', 'PHP'],
        note: "Vue.js is really awesome. Thanks Evan You!!!"
      },
      {
        start: '13:15',
        end: '13:30',
        name: "Rubik's Cube",
        description: "Play with my Rubik's Cube",
        tags: ['Logic', 'Puzzle', "Rubik's Cube"],
        note: "Learned a new algorithm."
      }
    ],
  },

  methods: {
    addItemAttribute: function(name, text) {
      this.items[0][name] = text;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to a Vue object similar to a normal javascript object. Reference: https://vuejs.org/api/#Options-Data

```
var obj = { a: 1};
obj.a // 1
obj.b // undefined
obj.b = 2;
// Now obj.b is defined
obj.b // 2
```

You can access data from Vue object like this

```
var vm = new Vue({
     data: {
         a: 1,
         b: 2
     }
});
```

Now we can access data from `$data` property

```
vm.$data.a === 1;
// You can add a new property
vm.$data.c = 3;
// it can be any object
vm.$data.d = {id: 1, name: 'ABC'}
```

You get and update `props` of a component using `component.options.props`

```
var component = Vue.component('props-demo-advanced', {
    props: {
        // just type check
        size: Number,
        // type check plus other validations
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          // warn if not two way bound
          twoWay: true
     }
   }
});
```

Let's say, we want to make name twoWay binding to false

```
component.options.props.name.twoWay = faslse
```

Or even you can change the entire object.

```
component.options.props = {
    size: Number,
    type: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      twoWay: false
 }
```

}

I don't know the above configurations are correct or not, I am just trying to convey the idea.

You should learn Javascript first, how objects are made, how to change them etc.

Comment: And how to add any object in  props?

Comment: @Slava Can you explain a bit, where do you want to add an object as property?

Comment: Any component have props object [link](http://vuejs.org/api/#props) . And vue don't have $props object

Comment: @Slava I've answer your question about `props` above

Comment: @Slava I even did not know about `Vue` before this, you should find these little things by your own.. everything is written there in documentation page.

Comment: Sorry, but add item in object for your way(obj.b = 2;) not works. Its not reactive, this works in console, but not render in site. I find way to add item and don't broke reactivity - `Vue.set(this.test, 'item3', 'item 3');` - this works fine. Sorry for your time.

Comment: @Slava No problem, there will be a way to update the UI after updating the data.. You can read the API.